# Excel VBA: Process a Raw Data Table via Grouping

Tags: excel, vba, group-by

I am looking for a way to group together rows of data *stored as a worksheet* (not from DB) and aggregate them as an entry in a separate view table worksheet. For example, I have 4 rows of data say:

```
GroupA GroupB Value1 Value2 Value3
A      A      1000   0      0
A      B      0      1000   0
A      B      0      0      1000
B      A      1000   0      0
```

When I aggregate to the view table, I wish to see something like:

```
GroupA GroupB Value1 Value2 Value3
A      A      1000   0      0
A      B      0      1000   1000
B      A      1000   0      0
```

This is quite an involved problem and I need something help in tackling this. How should I **first** group the rows together so that I can feed them into a processing function? From there, the aggregation should be fairly easy.

Comment: You can sort a table in Excel.

Comment: What types of aggregation do you need to support?  If only basic sum(), etc then you could use ADO to query the worksheet and summarise using `...group by [GroupA], [GroupB]`

Comment: Is using a Pivot Table an option? Pivot Tables designed for exactly that sort of analysis.

Comment: Essentially, I need to collapse rows into one another as in the example above given that they are of the same grouping. I will take a look at ADO.

Comment: Using the Subtotal tool in excel will do exactly this type of outlining.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using ADO.  One proviso is that the workbook does need to have been saved: ADO needs a path to work with.

```
Sub SqlSummary()

Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sPath, icount
Dim f As ADODB.Field
Dim sSQL As String
Dim sRange1 As String
Dim rngresults As Range


    sSQL = " select a.[GroupA],a.[GroupB], sum(a.[Value1]) as [Value1], " & _
    " sum(a.[Value2]) as [Value2], sum(a.[Value3]) as [Value3] from <r1> a " & _
    " group by a.[GroupA], a.[GroupB] "

    sRange1 = RangeName(shtData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

    If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> "" Then
      sPath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Else
      MsgBox "Workbook being queried must be saved first..."
      Exit Sub
    End If

    oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & sPath & _
               ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'"

    sSQL = Replace(sSQL, "<r1>", sRange1)
    Debug.Print sSQL
    oRS.Open sSQL, oConn

    If Not oRS.EOF Then

       shtDump.UsedRange.ClearContents
       Set rngresults = shtDump.Range("A1")
       icount = 0
       For Each f In oRS.Fields
          rngresults(1).Offset(0, icount).Value = f.Name
          icount = icount + 1
       Next f
       rngresults(1).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset oRS

    Else

       MsgBox "No records found"

    End If

End Sub

Function RangeName(r As Range) As String
    RangeName = "[" & r.Parent.Name & "$" & _
                r.Address(False, False) & "]"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pivot table generated in Excel 2010.  In 2007/10 you can have the labels repeat for each row, as the Group A does below.  GroupA and GroupB are set as row fields with the rest as value fields.  Grand Totals are turned off.  The view is set to Classic Pivot Table:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to create custom columns in the pivot table i.e. Sum of Value1 and Value2?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a calculated field.  If possible, I'd calculate it in the source data and just pivot off that column.

Comment: Question on pivot tables: Can you create a table such that the column labels are staggered so you can have something like 
GroupA GroupB Value1 Value2 GroupC Value3 GroupD?

Comment: No. All the grouped rows have to be at the left and all the values at the right. However, after the pivot table is created and summing your data the way you want, you can copy the results to a new worksheet and format it any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this through one formula, if you copy only your group fields into a new sheet, then use the Remove Duplicates tool (available from Excel 2007), so that your left with only unique records to query againist, then add this formula for each of your value fields:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet2!$B2)
SUMIFS([sum_range],[criteria_range1],[criteria1],[criteria_range2],[criteria2])
```

Comment: Note that SumIfs is available in 2007/10.  In previous versions you could use SumProduct instead.